# passing argument to biber in WinEdt

Tags: biber, winedt

I use WinEdt 9.1 with both biber (version 2.7) and bibtex. When I call biber, I want to pass the `--nostdmacros` argument to it. How may I do this?

Ordinarily, I would just go to Execution Modes > Console Applications, select "BibTeX" in the "Accessories" box, and add my argument to the "Switches" field. But I cannot do that in this case: I need to use WinEdt for bibtex as well, and bibtex doesn't recognize the `--nostdmacros` argument. I need to find a different way to pass this argument to biber.

Here is the relevant part of my MainMenu.ini:

```
ITEM="Biber"
  CAPTION="Biber"
  IMAGE="Biber"
  MACRO=`Assign("Old-BibTeX-Executable","%$('BibTeX-Executable');");`+
        `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","biber.exe");`+
        `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\BibTeX.edt');`+
        `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","%$('Old-BibTeX-Executable');");`+
        `Release("Old-BibTeX-Executable");`
  SHORTCUT="49218::Ctrl+Alt+B"
  REQ_FILTER=:%O\%N.bcf*"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
```

Is there a way to change this entry so that I can pass the argument to biber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Note, however, that `--nostdmodes` seems not to be a valid biber option. Perhaps did you mean `--nostdmacros`?

Anyway, choose the right option and substitute it in the following lines which have to replace the original lines:

```
  ITEM="Biber"
    CAPTION="Biber"
    IMAGE="Biber"
    MACRO=`Assign("Old-BibTeX-Executable","%$('BibTeX-Executable');");`+
          `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","biber.exe");`+
          `Assign("Old-BibTeX-Switches","%$('BibTeX-Switches');");`+
          `Assign("BibTeX-Switches","--nostdmacros");`+
          `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\BibTeX.edt');`+
          `Assign("BibTeX-Executable","%$('Old-BibTeX-Executable');");`+
          `Assign("BibTeX-Switches","%$('Old-BibTeX-Switches');");`+
          `Release("Old-BibTeX-Executable");`+
          `Release("Old-BibTeX-Switches");`
    SHORTCUT="49218::Ctrl+Alt+B"
    REQ_FILTER=:%O\%N.bcf*"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
```

Remember to reload `MainMenu.ini` through the shortcut <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. And `--nostdmacros` is indeed what I meant -- I edited the original post accordingly.